# What is the relationship between the metaclass of Base and Derived class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, metaclass

In Ruby, we could use `super` within singleton method to call the corresponding super class's singleton method, like the following code shows.

```
class Base
  def self.class_method
    puts "Base class method"
  end
end

class Derived < Base
  def self.class_method
    puts "Derived class method"
    super
  end
end

Derived.class_method
# Derived class method
# Base class method
```

However, I don't seem quite get how that call to `super` within `Derived.class_method` could reach `Base.class_method`. I'd assume that `class_method` is defined on their metaclass, does that mean their metaclass has parent/child relationship? (I can't quite confirm that by experiments)

*Update*: I'm asking this question because I remembered seeing *somewhere* there's some kind of relationship bettwen base and derived class' metaclass (but I can't find it any more). In addition to know how actually `super` works, I'd also like to confirm whether the two metaclasses are totally separate or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are four class objects in play here:

```
<Class>---class---><Class>
Base               #Base
   ^                  ^
   |                  |
   |                  |
 super              super
   |                  |
   |                  |
<Class>            <Class>
Derived---class--->#Derived
```

Nomenclature:

- <...> is the class of each object.
- The name of the class is on the second line.
- If the name starts with #, it's the eigenclass (aka singleton class).
- super points to a class's superclass
- class points to the class's class.

When you call Derived.class_method, Ruby follows the "right one and then up" rule: First go to the object's class, then follow the superclass chain up, stopping when the method is found:

- The receiver of the "class_method" call is Derived.  So follow the chain right to Derived's class object, which is its eigenclass (#Derived).
- ## Derived does not define the method, so Ruby follows the chain up the chain to #Derived's superclass, which is #Base.
- The method is found there, so Ruby dispatches the message to #Base.class_method

You don't think I knew all this stuff off the top of my head, did you?  Here's where my brain got all this meta juju: [Metaprogramming Ruby](http://pragprog.com/titles/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby).

**Part 2.**  How to make an "eigenclass" (aka "singleton class") come out of hiding

```
class Object
  def eigenclass
    class << self
      self
    end
  end
end
```

This method will return the eigenclass of any object.  Now, what about classes?  Those are objects, too.

```
p Derived.eigenclass               # => #<Class:Derived>
p Derived.eigenclass.superclass    # => #<Class:Base>
p Base.eigenclass                  # => #<Class:Base>
```

Note: Above is from Ruby1.9.  When run under Ruby 1.8, you get a surprise:

```
p Derived.eigenclass.superclass    # => #<Class:Class>
```

Comment: Is there a way to 'see' the relationship between #Base and #Derived? e.g., like the normal `.superclass`.

Comment: I added the trick that gets an eigenclass out of hiding.  But the diagram is not consistent with what the trick shows :(

Comment: well ... #<Class:Derived> is not #<Class:Base>, that's my problem ... Dose the link from #Derived to #Base really exist?

Comment: As far as I know, Ruby has exactly one way to do method dispatch: "right then up."  For that to be true, Then #Derived's superclass must be #Base.  However, the evidence contradicts that.

Another great theory ruined by the available evidence.

Comment: @Wayne, your theory is correct, it's just that the #class and #super methods never return eigenclasses - eigenclasses are somewhat 'hidden' in Ruby, see here: http://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2008/10/25/the-secret-life-of-singletons/

Comment: Ah, got it.  Run under Ruby 1.9, the results are as expected.  Under Ruby1.8, our trick for exposing the eigenclass's superclass does not work.  Under Ruby 1.9, it does.

Comment: make that #superclass (not #super as i stated). And yeah #superclass behaves differently in 1.9 in that it doesn't hide eigenclasses. In 1.8 though #superclass returns the 'eigenclass of the first real superclass'. So given that Class is the first real (i.e non eigenclass or iclass) superclass #superclass will returns Class's eigenclass :)

Comment: Even stranger (under 1.8): `Derived.eigenclass.superclass => #<Class:Class>`, but after a call to `Derived.eigenclass.eigenclass`, `Derived.eigenclass.superclass => #<Class:#<Class:Derived>>`. Both calls return `#<Class:Base>` under 1.9.

Comment: @jleedev, interesting point, it seems that in Ruby 1.8 the #superclass method (when invoked on an eigenclass) returns (for some bizarre reason) the CLASS of that eigenclass (rather than its superclass): here's the piece of code from the `rb_class_superclass` method in class.c.   `if (FL_TEST(klass, FL_SINGLETON)) super = RBASIC(klass)->klass;`

Answer (score 4):

To clarify and correct what i wrote in the comments regarding the way Ruby hides/exposes eigenclasses, here is the situation:

Ruby 1.8:

(1) The `Object#class` method always returns the first real (non eigenclass or iclass) superclass of the *actual* class of an object. 
e.g

```
o = Object.new
class << o; end
o.class #=> returns Object, even though the _actual_ class is the eigenclass of o
```

In other words, the `Object#class` method will never return an eigenclass, it passes over them
and instead returns the first 'real' class it finds in the inheritance hierarchy.

(2) The `Class#superclass` method has two cases. If the receiver is not an eigenclass then it simply returns the superclass. However, if the receiver *is* an eigenclass then this method returns the *actual* (i.e not necessarily real) class of the receiver.

```
# case where receiver is a normal class (i.e not an eigenclass)
Module.superclass #=> Object (behaves as expected)

# case where receiver is an eigenclass
class << Module; superclass; end #=> returns Class, this is NOT the superclass
```

From above, `Class#superclass` behaves as expected in the case of a normal class, but for the eigenclass example it states the superclass of the eigenclass of Module is Class which is not true. From this diagram http://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2008/10/25/the-secret-life-of-singletons/ we know that the superclass of the eigenclass of Module is actually the eigenclass of Object. I am unsure why Ruby 1.8 has this strange behaviour.

Ruby 1.9:

(1) The `Object#class` method behaves identically to the 1.8 version.

(2) The `Class#superclass` method no longer has two cases, it now treats eigenclasses the same way it treats normal classes and returns the actual superclass as expected.

e.g

```
class << Module; superclass; end #=> #<Class:Object>
```

Answer (score 3):

This diagram explains the relationship: http://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2008/11/25/a-complete-ruby-class-diagram/

Also, here are some other posts that explain more the intricacies of eigenclasses: 
http://www.klankboomklang.com/2007/10/05/the-metaclass/

http://www.klankboomklang.com/2007/09/21/the-singleton-class/

And here's a fairly hard-going one that explains more than you'd probably like to know:
http://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2008/10/25/the-secret-life-of-singletons/

Comment: I finally got around to reading your hard-going post.  Great stuff!